# Unresolved error startActivityForResult() but startActivity() is ok

Tags: android

I'm using startActivity() in my code and want to change it to startActivityForResult() but doing so is resulting in a compilation error of 'Cannot resolve method startActivityForResult'

If I put the two next to each other in the code, there's no compilation error for the first but there is for the second, how can this be?

```
 getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);             
 getApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: try to run from activity context instead of application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` returns an `Application` object. `startActivityForResult()` is a method on `Activity` and `Fragment`, not `Application` or `Context`.

And, since `getApplicationContext()` is pointless here, just get rid of it, and call `startActivity()` (and, perhaps, `startActivityForResult()`) on the existing `Context` (whatever `this` is).

Comment: I'm calling it from within a WearMessageListenerService derived object, therefore how can I call it as WearMessageListenerService  is neither an Activity nor Fragment. Is it possible to call it in this situation?

Comment: @Piepants: No, you cannot call `startActivityForResult()` in something that inherits from `Service`.